# JQUERY --- Get values in Json - not working

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting errors in getting my array in JSON string, I have simplified my script below to make it easier to understand

Here is my return MVC controller

```
   message = $"{ ViewData["fileLocation"]} , { id}  ";
            return Json(message);
```

and here is my front end

```
  $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/Upload/AjaxUpload",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formData,
            success: function (message) {
                alert(message);

                var msg = $.parseJSON(message);
                alert(msg[0]);
                $(".classify").attr("src", message[0]);

                $('#ajax_loading2').html('Congrats image uploaded.\n Upload ID: ' + message[1]);
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: What is `message = $"{ ViewData["fileLocation"]} , { id} ";`? Please, share the method of your API controller and show the error message.

Comment: error messages are: VM1617:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: The API controller simply takes the value of the upload file location and assign it to ViewData["filelocation"] and the value of the PK and assign it to id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what, you're trying to do here.

```
message = $"{ ViewData["fileLocation"]} , { id}  ";
```

Try returning an (anonymous) object

```
var message = new { fileLocation = ViewData["fileLocation"], id = id};
return Json(message);
```

Then in JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Upload/AjaxUpload",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function (message) {
        alert(message);

        var msg = $.parseJSON(message);
        alert(msg.fileLocation);
        $(".classify").attr("src", message.fileLocation);

        $('#ajax_loading2')
            .html('Congrats image uploaded.\n Upload ID: ' + msg.id);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, use C# class to set up the data. Then convert it to JSON. In js, you can use those properties to from the JSON.

Comment: thanks for your reply, basically what I am trying to do is return a url using ViewData["fileLocation"] and return a Primary key using "id"  and assign the values to the class (.classify) and attach the value of the ID to the label ajax_loading2

Comment: @Ehi That's exactly what my answer should do. Passing `new { fileLocation = ViewData["fileLocation"], id = id})` to `Json()` should create a JsonResult with the properly formatted JSON representing an object with 2 properties (fileLocation and id) that you can access directly in the `success` function. Does it not work?

Comment: @phuzi yes you are correct, there was a slight error in your script which initially confused me as I changed .html('Congrats image uploaded.\n Upload ID: ' + msg.id); to .html('Congrats image uploaded.\n Upload ID: ' + message.id);

Comment: @phuzi Thank you